# Why did Newton state his first law separately even though it is apparently a direct consequence of the second law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If $F=0$, $F=ma \implies m\frac{(v-u)}{t}=0\implies v-u=0 \implies v=u $

Which is essentially Newton's first law.

Answer (score 1):

[ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind)'s link gives you the correct answers.

But here is an additional side-note to be considered:

$$a= \frac{v-u}{t}\;;$$

Hmm; this is **not** true in *general*.

What you would want to say is that

$$F~=~ m\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} = ma~=~0$$

However, that doesn't mean that the body has constant velocity; for in some cases

$$\dot a ~\ne~ 0\;.$$